# Firefox Submit Handler for Buttons outside of Form

Tags: jquery, forms, firefox

Given the following **HTML:**

```
<form id='test' action='URL'>...</form>
<button type='submit' form='test' formaction='OTHERURL'>submit</button>
```

When I assign a jquery submit handler to the form, it does not recognize the submission in FireFox. In Chrome, Opera, Safari this is not a problem.

- Does anyone have any experience with this?
- What is the best workaround to this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I cannot understand the problem because on my computer the button type submit works in all browsers.

So just to suggest you something of different I propose you to handle the click event on the buttons and after trigger the submit event like in the following snippet:

```js
$(document).on('click', 'button:submit', function(e) {
  var frm = $('#' + e.target.getAttribute('form'));
  var formAction = e.target.formAction.length > 0 ? e.target.formAction : frm.attr('action');
  document.querySelector('#result') += '<p>Button Submit Clicked: ' + formAction + '</p><br>';
  $('#' + e.target.getAttribute('form')).trigger('submit');
});
$(document).on('submit', '#test', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  document.querySelector('#result') += '<p>submit</p><br>';
});
```

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>

<form id='test' action='z.json'>
    First name:<br>
    <input type="text" name="firstname"><br>
    Last name:<br>
    <input type="text" name="lastname"><br><br>
</form>
<button type="submit" form='test'>Submit</button>
<button type='submit' form='test' formaction='http://www.google.it'>Submit as New url</button>
<div id='result'></div>
```